# Setting Page Update Profile Name in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ngmodel

Hi Guys I need to change the existing profile name in settings page. 
1. First Name must be displayed in Username: {{name}} 
2. I have given button to show dialog box to change name, when clicked save the name must be changed and displayed in the Username:{{name}} That is all i needed.. I need code like below, This code is just a example..

```js
var app = angular.module('AngularApp', ['ngMaterial']);
app.controller('SettingCtrl', ['$scope', '$mdDialog',
  function($scope, $mdDialog) {
    $scope.name = "test";
    $scope.ChangeName = function(ev) {
      $mdDialog.show({
          controller: SetDialogController,
          template: '<md-dialog aria-label="Add insert" md-theme="dialogtheme"><md-content>' +
            '<form name="ChangeName"><div layout layout-sm="column"><md-input-container flex>' +
            '<label>Client Name</label><input ng-model="newname" placeholder="New Name">' +
            '</md-input-container><div></form> </md-content>' +
            '<div class="md-dialog-actions" layout="row"> <span flex></span>' +
            '<md-button ng-click="cancel()"> Cancel </md-button>' +
            '<md-button ng-click="saveClient()" class="md-warn"> Save </md-button>' +
            '</div></md-dialog>',
          targetEvent: ev,
          clickOutsideToClose: true
        })
        .then(function(answer) {
          $scope.status = 'You said the information was "' + answer + '".';
        }, function() {
          $scope.status = 'You cancelled the dialog.';
        });
    };
  }
]);

function SetDialogController($scope, $mdDialog) {
  $scope.saveClient = function() {}
  $scope.cancel = function() {
    $mdDialog.cancel();
  };
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
  <title>ViewSalesVisit</title>
  <!-- <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->
  <link href="js/angular-material.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
  <!-- <script src="cordova.js"></script> -->
  <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/angular-material.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <!-- your app's js -->
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="AngularApp" ng-controller="SettingCtrl">
  <div>
    <md-content md-scroll-y>
      <md-toolbar class="md-toolbar-tools" layout-align="center">
        <h3>Settings</h3>
      </md-toolbar>
      <div>
        <h1>Username: {{name}}</h1>
        <md-button class="md-primary md-raised" ng-click="ChangeName($event)" flex="100" flex-gt-md="auto">
          Change Username
        </md-button>
      </div>
    </md-content>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Thank you in advance guys..